# Xamarin.Forms Editor resizing jitter in UWP project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

Why is there a jitter on `Editor` resizing on a new line?

```
<StackLayout>
    <Editor AutoSize="TextChanges"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Also the case when I try manually resize it inside `OnTextChanged` (previously removing `AutoSize="TextChanges"`). It might be eliminated by waiting for a while:

```
protected override void OnTextChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    HeightRequest += 10;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Also there is no such problem for a regular `UWP` project using corresponding `TextBox` class with `AcceptsReturn="True"`.

Smooth textbox resizing in regular UWP project:

[image]

Jittering editor from xamarin UWP project:

[image]

How can I fix this?

**Additional:**

With `AutoSize` and `Sleep` (`HeightRequest` removed):

[image]

Comment: You are hanging the UI thread via the `Sleep` statement, why?

Comment: @SushiHangover this is for testing and debugging purpose.

Comment: `Sleep` hangs the current thread, and in the case of `OnTextChanged` that is the UI thread, so I would expect the UI to jitter as you are interrupting the UI layout process

Comment: @SushiHangover, you take my question wrong. First it jitter just as it is (without sleep, of course), then I try to find out what is the reason and override `OnTextChanged`. It helps to clear up that timing matters somehow.

Comment: That looks like an interaction between `AutoSize` and dynamically changing `HeightRequest`. You've told Editor to recalculate height twice, two different ways. What happens if you do just one of those?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I'm not doing both. Just `AutoSize` or the second. Separately.

Comment: ahh, that makes more sense. If you AutoSize, remove the HeightRequest, but leave in the Sleep, does that avoid the jitter?

Comment: Is there anything else on page that is updating? Seems like something is causing two layout cycles. Even so, its odd that one somehow isn't autosized.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I have added another gif. And no, nothing else is on the page.

Comment: ok. I see it still scrolls up before resizing, so a bit messy. I don't see anything else you can do. If you make a new solution from scratch, with nothing in it but this page, and it still happens, then can you upload to a public github, and post link here, with @NicoZhu-MSFT mentioned in comment?

Comment: Yep, I could reproduce this problem, and it looks a bug for Editor, please feel free post this problem within Xamarin Forms Issue Box [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues).